# How to fix bad rendering of graphics in linux in recovery mode?

Tags: gnome, graphics, data-recovery

I have a system running ubuntu 20.04, whenever I boot it in recovery mode,the menu of recovery mode is not rendered properly.

desktop environment - gnome 3.36

On using the system after booting, the system graphics behaves normally.

[image: screen when ubuntu booted under recovery mode]

How to fix the problem?

Comment: You could try different cables and hope the problem was a bad cable.
I've only seen something similar just before the GPU died.

Comment: I have another operating system ubuntu mate 18.04 in dual boot. It does not show any problem of graphics at all. So the problem of hardware gets ruled out. It is 100% a software issue.